# Installing Cartopy using souce file

Tags: python, installation, cartopy

I'm trying to install Cartopy on Windows for Anaconda.  However, it seems no source files are ready for windows.  Any other place I can get files windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  to install Cartopy and Shapely.  Also, since I two local copies of Python one is Anaconda and one is just Python 2.7.  I install the files two times one to each directory.  Below is a link of the dependencies you will need.  If you are running Anaconda a lot of them are already present.

http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/building_from_source/index.html#building-from-source

Comment: Christoph's unofficial packages are the only source I know of for Cartopy on windows. The original ticket to do the work can be found here, for your reference: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/251

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm wanting to do more with mapping than just using Base Map.  It seems this is the next step.